# How do I normalize the audio volume of my FLAC collection?

Tags: audio, flac

It seems that some CDs have a much lower general audio volume than others. This is not a problem if listening to an entire album, but it becomes a problem, when listening in shuffle mode: there is a constant need to reach out for the volume knob.

Of course, sometimes a title is gentle quite intentionally, but that's mostly occuring in classical albums or musicals, which are not intended to be listed to in shuffle mode.

However, on my wife's flower power collection, this is quite annoying.

Hence the question: **How do I automatically adjust the volume level of all the 1000+ FLAC tracks in a folder without loss of quality, possibly using a script?**

(Interestingly, when playing her collection via her new Sony walkman there is no noticeable volume difference; they must have a way to adjust the output volume automatically, perhaps on-the-fly.)

Comment: Not quite a dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/1017448/linux-how-do-i-adjust-an-mp3-file-to-have-the-same-apparent-volume-as-another/1017562#1017562 but the answer is the same.